# Is there a short way to check distinctiveness of values without using 'if' and multiple 'and's in PHP?

Tags: php, duplicates

I am writing some code and I need to compare some values. The point is that none of the variables should have the same value as another. For example:

```
$x=1
$y=2
$z=3
if ($x != $y and $y != $z and $x != $z) {
#do something 
}
```

Now, it is easy to see that in a case of code with more variables, the if statement becomes very long and full of ands. Is there a short way to tell PHP that no 2 variable values should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put all the values in an array and check if the length of the array was the same as the length of only the unique values in the array:

```
if (count(array($x, $y, $z)) == count(array_unique(array($x, $y, $z)))) {
    // all values different. do something
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TWJ76)

Comment: Very nice solution

Comment: @BunnyDavis it wouldn't be as performant as writing out all the values as you show in the question, but definitely a lot more readable!